# BulkCopy Firebird database to Azure SQL Server databasae

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, firebird

I am looking to copy data from a Firebird database into a SQL Azure database. I have a small program that SQL bulk copies from one SQL datatable to another.

Is possible to do something similar with the Firebird and the SQL Server without exporting data to CSV first?

Comment: A commercial tool to achieve that https://convertdb.com/firebird/azure

Comment: Of course it is possible, you may need to write it yourself though (select from firebird, insert each row into azure). Not sure why you think it wouldn't be possible without using CSV as an intermediary. But your question is very unspecific, which makes it too broad, and borderline asking for tool recommendations.

Comment: [FBExport](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/manual.html) can produce its output to stdout and can be piped to another process. If something similar is available for SQL Server to accept the data on stdin then you may be able to avoid the intermediate file. There's always the option of selecting from one system and inserting into the other as mentioned by Mark above.

Comment: I know I have to write it myself, but currently I have a EPOS system in the location I work that uses a firebird database and never had any experience with them. I can import from their reporting system via a csv file but am looking to complete automate that proceedure.  As I have no experience with Firebird was just querying whether it was actually possible before settling down to the code, the EPOS is base across an internal network and the data needs to be exported to azure for remote data analysis as the there is several different geographical locations involved.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would avoid using CSV, because there is too many implementation-specific corner cases. For example, MS Excel by default  can not read proper CSV files until commas would be replaced with semicolon, violating the very name.